# Get current time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving current local time on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566265/retrieving-current-local-time-on-iphone)

How to get current time ?(hour:minute:second)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
[dateFormatter release];
```