# How to implement a Count Down timer for a quiz application ?

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

In my quiz application , I want to include a count down timer for the entire quiz. Can anyone give me link or any idea regarding implementation of a count down timer ?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Have you tried anything or do you have a specific area that is giving you trouble? Have you looked at NSTimer? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: first you have tried to search any link for it ??? if yes then give us too :) and if no then please try more and more you will be success :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int seconds = time % 60;
int minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
theTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: @iosdev, u can get time in strings, follow this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566265/retrieving-current-local-time-on-iphone