# Getting location and acceleration information

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I am developing an iPhone App in which I have to get the acceleration and deceleration with which user is moving. Actually this App will work as a chronometer. How can I get the latitude and longitude anh how can I calculate the acceleration and deceleration. Any sample code or information link will be better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) for Location.

Also [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html) for movement

**Edit**

Have a look at [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1) which lets you do things with headings and speeds using your location.

Comment: @Abizem: I am talking about the acceleration with which user is moving. I am not talking about the movement of device. I meant that if user is participating in the car race then how can I calculate the acceleration of car using the Latitude and Longitude (using GPS).

Comment: @Harsh Acceleration = change in velocity / time. Velocity = change in distance / time. You can find almost all the unknowns from the information provided in the post above! You may need to use an NSTimer to calculate time.

Comment: Perhaps a better way of calculating change in time is to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358207/iphone-how-to-get-current-milliseconds