# Get current date in milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, date, time

Can any one give me an idea how to get the current date in milliseconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a precise time, for example in milliseconds in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c)

Comment: When you say the current date in milliseconds, what do you mean?  Can you provide an example of your expected output for a specific date?

Answer (score 107):

There are several ways of doing this, although my personal favorite is:

```
CFAbsoluteTime timeInSeconds = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

You can read more about this method [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent). You can also create a NSDate object and get time by calling [timeIntervalSince1970](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970) which returns the [seconds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval) since 1/1/1970:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

And in Swift:

```
let timeInSeconds: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: im trying tis following code NSTimeInterval milisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
 
 
 NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse ---- %d",milisecondedDate);

Comment: @siva i am getting same thing any idea ?

Comment: The problem is with the NSLog statement. NSTimeInterval is a typedefed double. Thus you should use %f instead of %d.

Comment: [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] returns an NSTimeInterval, which is a duration in seconds, not milli-seconds.

Comment: Note that `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` returns the time relative to the reference date `Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT`. Not that a reference date was given in the question, but be aware that this is not a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: is timestamp is based on `GMT`?

Comment: [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] returns time in seconds and not in milliseconds.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran The `timeIntervalSince1970` is since January 1, 1970 UTC (in seconds). And UTC is identical to GMT.

Comment: but isn't CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() return time in "seconds" unit also?

Comment: author asked in ms, not in seconds!

Answer (score 64):

Casting the NSTimeInterval directly to a long overflowed for me, so instead I had to cast to a long long.

```
long long milliseconds = (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
```

The result is a 13 digit timestamp as in Unix.

Comment: This wont return the actual milliseconds because timeIntervalSince1970 returns the interval in seconds, so we wont have the desired millis accuracy.

Comment: The `timeIntervalSince1970 ` method does return at the seconds on the whole number, however it is a `double` that also includes the fractional second as well which can be arithmetically converted to milliseconds. Hence, the multiplication by 1000.

Comment: @wileymap Yup, you are right. I figured it out later on

Comment: `long long`? this lang is so weird

Comment: @user924 Couldn't agree more. That's why I stopped writing it. ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
NSTimeInterval milisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
```

Comment: im trying tis following code NSTimeInterval milisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000); NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse ---- %d",milisecondedDate); -- but it showing the value in negative val -- like ResponseTIME ---- 556610175
ResponseTIME ---- -1548754395

Comment: try using %f placeholder instead of %d. If that doesn't help - remove the multiplication by 1000

Comment: @Eimantas,When i try to use %f ...                                Im getting time as Follows                                          Response Time =  1306494959011.239014
Response Time = 1306494910724.744141

If it's ms then the above time is more than an hour.

Comment: The current date is time interval in seconds since 1970. You didn't mention about reference date anything.

Comment: i wil take only the current date time interval

Comment: I don't understand your requirements at all now.

Comment: i mean,i want to display the current date in the form of millisecond,Pls get the proper solutions

Comment: `NSTimeInterval`, though it's just a typedef for `double`, is used only to express seconds (and fractions of seconds). Semantically, it makes no sense to assign to a value representing milliseconds to an `NSTimeInterval` variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can just do this:

```
long currentTime = (long)(NSTimeInterval)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

this will return a value en milliseconds, so if you multiply the resulting value by 1000 (as suggested my Eimantas) you'll overflow the long type and it'll result in a negative value.

For example, if I run that code right now, it'll result in

```
currentTime = 1357234941
```

and

```
currentTime /seconds / minutes / hours / days = years
1357234941 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 = 43.037637652207
```

Answer (score 7):

```
extension NSDate {

    func toMillis() -> NSNumber {
        return NSNumber(longLong:Int64(timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
    }

    static func fromMillis(millis: NSNumber?) -> NSDate? {
        return millis.map() { number in NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(number) / 1000)}
    }

    static func currentTimeInMillis() -> NSNumber {
        return NSDate().toMillis()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@JavaZava your solution is good, but if you want to have a 13 digit long value to be consistent with the time stamp formatting in Java or JavaScript (and other languages) use this method:

```
NSTimeInterval time = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]); // returned as a double
long digits = (long)time; // this is the first 10 digits
int decimalDigits = (int)(fmod(time, 1) * 1000); // this will get the 3 missing digits
long timestamp = (digits * 1000) + decimalDigits;
```

or (if you need a string):

```
NSString *timestampString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%d",digits ,decimalDigits];
```

Comment: NSString *timestampString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%03d",digits ,decimalDigits]; is correct actually. In your case if decimalDigits value is less than 100 will produce wrong result.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned before,
 **[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] returns an NSTimeInterval, which is a duration in seconds, not milli-seconds.**

You can visit https://currentmillis.com/ to see how you can get in the language you desire. Here is the list -

```
ActionScript    (new Date()).time
C++ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()
C#.NET  DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
Clojure (System/currentTimeMillis)
Excel / Google Sheets*  = (NOW() - CELL_WITH_TIMEZONE_OFFSET_IN_HOURS/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000
Go / Golang time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000
Hive*   unix_timestamp() * 1000
Java / Groovy / Kotlin  System.currentTimeMillis()
Javascript  new Date().getTime()
MySQL*  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000
Objective-C (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0)
OCaml   (1000.0 *. Unix.gettimeofday ())
Oracle PL/SQL*  SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 FROM DUAL
Perl    use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday); print gettimeofday;
PHP round(microtime(true) * 1000)
PostgreSQL  extract(epoch FROM now()) * 1000
Python  int(round(time.time() * 1000))
Qt  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()
R*  as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1000
Ruby    (Time.now.to_f * 1000).floor
Scala   val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
SQL Server  DATEDIFF(ms, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())
SQLite* STRFTIME('%s', 'now') * 1000
Swift*  let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
VBScript / ASP  offsetInMillis = 60000 * GetTimeZoneOffset()
WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now()) * 1000 - offsetInMillis + Timer * 1000 mod 1000
```

For objective C I did something like below to print it -

```
long long mills = (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
 NSLog(@"Current date %lld", mills);
```

Hopw this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Cconvert `NSTimeInterval` `milisecondedDate` value to `nsstring` and after that convert into `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods to get current date in milliseconds.

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

OR

```
double CurrentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

Source:
[iPhone: How to get current milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358207/iphone-how-to-get-current-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)GetCurrentTimeStamp
    {
        NSDateFormatter *objDateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [objDateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString    *strTime = [objDateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString    *strUTCTime = [self GetUTCDateTimeFromLocalTime:strTime];//You can pass your date but be carefull about your date format of NSDateFormatter.
        NSDate *objUTCDate  = [objDateformat dateFromString:strUTCTime];
        long long milliseconds = (long long)([objUTCDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);

        NSString *strTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",milliseconds];
        NSLog(@"The Timestamp is = %@",strTimeStamp);
    }

 - (NSString *) GetUTCDateTimeFromLocalTime:(NSString *)IN_strLocalTime
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate  *objDate    = [dateFormatter dateFromString:IN_strLocalTime];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
        NSString *strDateTime   = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:objDate];
        return strDateTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the time in milliseconds `(long)(NSTimeInterval)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])`.

Answer (score 0):

An extension on date is probably the best way to about it.

```
extension NSDate {
    func msFromEpoch() -> Double {
        return self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    }
}
```