# Getting current time in milliseconds Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I've tried to google around but I still can't find the best answer.

All I want is very simple, I just want to get the current time in milliseconds.

How can I do that in cocos2d?

Comment: I think this has been discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358207/iphone-how-to-get-current-milliseconds

Answer (score 4):

First, a class variable:

```
CGFloat gameTime;
```

Then in your class initialize:

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

Finally, while still in your class:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)delta {
    gameTime += delta;
}
```

delta is the milliseconds since the last call of update. Save gameTime somewhere in a database for lifetime gameTime.

Answer (score 2):

```
try this

time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

CCLog("year------->%04d",timeinfo->tm_year+1900);
CCLog("month------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_mon+1);
CCLog("day------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_mday);

CCLog("hour------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_hour);
CCLog("mintus------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_min);
CCLog("seconds------->%02d",timeinfo->tm_sec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert the current time into a float value, then multiply the current time by 10^3  to convert it into milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

To get only milliseconds

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];

NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

float seconds = str.intValue;

float miliSeconds = seconds / 1000; // HERE is your answer
```

If you want to get full time format replace

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the current time in seconds and multiply by 1000 go get number of milliseconds:

```
double ms = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() * 1000.0;
```