# Swift: gettimeofday and Unsafe Pointers

Tags: null, swift, gettimeofday, unsafe-pointers

The code in Swift

```
...
var time:timeval?
gettimeofday(UnsafePointer<timeval>, UnsafePointer<()>) // this is the method expansion before filling in any data
...
```

The code in Objective C

```
...
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
...
```

I have been trying to find more information on UnsafePointer and alternatives to passing NULL, but I may be barking up the wrong tree.

If anyone knows how to get the equivilant code working in Swift, that would be great. If there is a good explanation of what's going on with it that would be even better!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `let now = NSDate()` is simpler...

Comment: If I remember correctly, NSDate was too slow and/or inaccurate when I first coded the UIGestureRecognizer I use this in. I don't know if that would still be the case now, but I don't know if I want to test it at this point (converting my app to Swift, enough other problems)

Comment: `UIEvents` come with a `.timestamp` which is sub-millisecond. I guess if you need the microseconds then `timval` gives that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know one way to do it and this is as follows:

```
var time:timeval = timeval(tv_sec: 0, tv_usec: 0)
gettimeofday(&time, nil)
```

I had to initialize `time` with something so there actually was a struct at the address `&time` pointed to.

Comment: That was the first code I used, I didn't think about initialization though /facepalm/. Is the reason for needing it initialized that this is not a fully swift-ized method?

Comment: Well it actually makes sense to me. If you don't initialize it then there is no memory reserved for the struct and `&time` points to nowhere so gettimeofday() can't use the address to alter the struct.

Comment: Yes, that does make perfect sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @solenoid: I do not think that "reserving the memory" is the problem here. But Swift requires that every variable is initialized before it is used.

Comment: @solenoid: That's not true though, is it? I can define a variable with var myNil: String? and then use it everywhere where I would normally use an Optional like myFooFunction(withOptionalStringParameter: myNil)

Comment: @solenoid beause it needs to write to somewhere, it can only write to an allocated bit of memory, by instantiating `timeval` you align this allocated bit of memory to the specific data structure for a later use.