# Swift ios date as milliseconds Double or UInt64?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I'm not iOS developer but started learning Swift.

I try to convert some logic from Android project to iOS.

I have the following method:

```
func addGroupItemSample(sample : WmGroupItemSample){ // some custom class

    var seconds: NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    var  cuttDate:Double =  seconds*1000;

    var sampleDate: UInt64 = sample.getStartDate(); // <-- problematic place

if(sampleDate > cuttDate){
   // ....
  }
}
```

From the method above you can see that `sample.getStartDate()` returns type `UInt64`.

I thought it's like `long` in Java: `System.currentTimeMillis()`

But current time in milliseconds defined as `Double`.

Is it a proper way to mix `Double` and `UInt64` or do I need to represent all milliseconds as `Double` only?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift does not allow comparing different types.

`seconds` is a `Double` floating point value in seconds with sub-second accuracy.
`sampleDate` is a UInt64 but the units are not given.
`sampleDate` needs be converted to a `Double` floating point value with units of seconds.

```
var sampleDate: Double = Double(sample.getStartDate())
```

Then they can be compared:

```
if(sampleDate > cuttDate){}
```

Answer (score 30):

in iOS it is better to use double, but if you want to easy port your code and keep it consistent you can try this:

```
func currentTimeMillis() -> Int64{
    let nowDouble = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int64(nowDouble*1000)
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing Int64(..) + Int64(...) ?

Comment: Variable 'nowDouble' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constants

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative version, for Swift 3:

```
   /// Method to get Unix-style time (Java variant), i.e., time since 1970 in milliseconds. This 
   /// copied from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24655601/253938 and here:
   /// http://stackoverflow.com/a/7885923/253938
   /// (This should give good performance according to this: 
   ///  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12020300/253938 )
   ///
   /// Note that it is possible that multiple calls to this method and computing the difference may 
   /// occasionally give problematic results, like an apparently negative interval or a major jump 
   /// forward in time. This is because system time occasionally gets updated due to synchronization 
   /// with a time source on the network (maybe "leap second"), or user setting the clock.
   public static func currentTimeMillis() -> Int64 {
      var darwinTime : timeval = timeval(tv_sec: 0, tv_usec: 0)
      gettimeofday(&darwinTime, nil)
      return (Int64(darwinTime.tv_sec) * 1000) + Int64(darwinTime.tv_usec / 1000)
   }
```

Comment: To whoever gave me an up-vote on this today, please note that I've now edited the code to improve it in two ways - see the edit comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
func get_microtime() -> Int64{
    let nowDouble = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int64(nowDouble*1000)
}
```

> Working fine

Answer (score 1):

**Simple one-line code to get time token in UInt64**

**let time = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)**

print(time)   <----- prints time in UInt64

Additional tip:

Looking for timestamp with **10 Digit milliseconds since 1970 for API call then**

**let timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970**

print(timeStamp) <-- prints current time stamp