# How to save tableView separation after restart when connected to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to programming and currently trying things with firebase. I am building a newsfeed like app, which displays custom type cells in my tableView. I currently have the problem that after an app restart the separation is like the one in firebase. But I want the newest be first and stay there. I thought about saving the array in core data, but I don't like this option as much. So my question is: how do I sort the posts from newest to oldest?

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

var posts = [String]()
var timeRef = [String]()
var userRef = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSlideMenuButton()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("posts").observe( .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let newPost = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let post_title:String = newPost!["post_title"] as? String ?? "error"

        let newPostTime = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let post_time:String = newPostTime!["post_time"] as? String ?? "error"

        let newPostUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let post_user:String = newPostUser!["post_user"] as? String ?? "Team"

        self.posts.insert(post_title, at: 0)
        self.timeRef.insert(post_time, at: 0)
        self.userRef.insert(post_user, at: 0)

        self.newsfeedTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

(Tell me if you need more code)

Comment: You can `sort` array by `post_time` once you received it from firebase then reload your `tableView`.

Comment: But I need to use Calendar, right? So I can use the date for separation?

Comment: Yes and `post_time` should return a date or time interval of post creation time.

Comment: can u give me an example, please. Because I once watched a tutorial and didn't understand a thing D:

Comment: When you are creating a post and posting it to firebase you just need to give current time interval to `post_time` property. and here is how you can get current time interval https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358207/iphone-how-to-get-current-milliseconds.

Comment: oh i am not sending anything to firebase. I am just gettin Data. I type in the time manual

Comment: So you are creating post manually from firebase?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do. I am a beginner and not much into Databases

Comment: then you can create a date with time with correct formate then convert that string to `Date` once you received it into your project and sort it

Comment: Basically **never** use multiple arrays as table data source. Sorting three arrays to keep the same order is very expensive. Use a custom struct or class. What string format is `post_time`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with firebase but it might have something built in that might help you with that task as it's a common one.

Anyway, this is how you may do it with your method:

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

// dateStrings will be fetched from your database
let dateStrings = [
    "2018-12-07T09:21:42Z",
    "2018-12-07T09:19:42Z",
    "2018-12-07T09:20:42Z"
]

// here we're converting the strings to an actual Date types
let dates = dateStrings.compactMap { isoFormatter.date(from: $0) }

// sorting in descending order
let sortedDates = dates.sorted { $0 > $1 }

print(sortedDates)
/*
 prints-

 [
    2018-12-07 09:21:42 +0000,
    2018-12-07 09:20:42 +0000,
    2018-12-07 09:19:42 +0000
 ]
 */
```

You can use `isoFormatter.string(from: Date)` to upload a date to your database

Comment: I am using another date Format though (dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: So you may take a look on class `DateFormatter` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter